# cannot run command with processbuilder or runexec inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, tomcat, mongodump

I'm trying to execute a command from my Java web application (maven project with Tomcat 8 in Eclipse).
If I execute this command by the cmd line or by a .jar file there is no problem, but in Eclipse it doesn't work. 
I tried `ProcessBuilder` class and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` but both throw the same "file not found exception" exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mongodump": error=2, No such file or directory
```

The command i want to run is:

```
mongodump --db TweetsDB --collection Tweets --out ./TweetsDB_backup/
```

It seems that the runtime environments can't find the mongodump command (and/or the folder named in the command?)
Any suggestion?
Here it is my code:

```
public synchronized static void backup(){
Process p;
try {
    String dateTimeInString = dateTimeToString(Calendar.getInstance());
    System.out.println("backuppando "+dateTimeInString); 
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mongodump --db TweetsDB --collection Tweets --out ./backup/"); //override always the same db to save space
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Backup effettuato correttamente :)");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

This is the "process builder" variant :

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("mongodump", "--db", "TweetsDB","--collection", "Tweets", "--out" ,"./TweetsDB_backup/");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true); // equivalent of 2>&1
final Process process = builder.start();
InputStream es = process.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader esr = new InputStreamReader(es);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(esr);
String line;
while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Thanks,
Giulio

Comment: try absolute path to your .exe command; then you could also setup `builder.directory(workDir);`

Answer (score 0):

When you started the process with ProcessBuilder or Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), it would swallow any output from the process that is being started.

To see the real problem you need to get that output back.

With Runtime.exec() you need to use process.getErrorStream() and process.getInputStream() and set up threads to copy the output to somewhere you can see it.

with ProcessBuilder you can diurect the IO from the resulting process into the current (parent) processes using  ProcessBuilder.inheritIO() before you call ProcessBuilder.start().

Use `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()` to redirect the processes output to the servers log and you may find out what the error is.

try the following and see if it helps.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("mongodump", "--db", "TweetsDB","--collection", "Tweets", "--out" ,"./TweetsDB_backup/");
builder.inheritIO(); 
final Process process = builder.start();
```

Once you know what the error is you may be able to work out the solution.

I suspect you need to set some additional environment variables or something in the resulting process to get it to work.

Comment: I updated again the question and inserted what I did in the ProcessBuilder variant, the exception raises at builder.start() then I cannot read any error stream from the process

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it yet, but maybe you can do it this way :

```
Mongo client = new MongoClient();
client.getDB("myDb").command("mongodump ...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw `No such file or directory` is because Java can't get local path env. You should give absolute path of mongodump. Like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/mongodump --db TweetsDB --collection Tweets --out ./TweetsDB_backup/");
```